# Shared method of store fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

### Motivation

I store user credentials in redux store. They are filled when user logs in. I would like to have reusable method to fetch data with user's username and password.

---

#### State / auth

```
const initState = {
    isLoading: false,
    user: undefined,
    auth_err: false
};
```

#### My attempt

```
const fetchData = props => async (url, method, body) => {

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: method,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.btoa(props.user.username + ":" + props.user.password)
            },
            body: body
        });
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        user: state.auth.user
    }
};

export const SENDREQUEST = connect(mapStateToProps)(fetchData);
```

#### Call

```
const response = await SENDREQUEST("http://localhost:8080/users", "GET");
```

But once I call it I get:

> TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

---

Is there any way at all to create such one?
Any help would be appreciated ♥

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: @LucaKiebel When I mount component

Comment: I don't think you are using connect and mapStateToProps correctly. Check out official docs or this: https://gist.github.com/markerikson/121c77a01c453466361a9c6434a08620

It connects redux store with your component and not with function/method of component. Also, first letter of component should be capital letter.

Comment: @LazarNikolic I guess so, but it's only attempt. My main goal is to create reusable method to fetch data.

Comment: You can solve that by using a HOC that executes api requests and then sends the result back to the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you know about redux and its middleware.

First of all the error comes from passing `fetchData` to the return value of `connect` : `connect` returns a function which is a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) : takes a component, returns a component which is a `class` here that  cannot be called as a function as you do.

A solution for your problem is to use `mapDispatchToProps` and a middleware, roughly as follow :

```
class LoginFormPresenter {
  render () {
    // render your login
    return <form onSubmit={this.props.logUser}></form>
  }
}

// This makes the LoginFormPresenter always receive a props `logUser`
const LoginFormConnector = connect((state => { user: state.user }), {
  logUser: (e) => (
    // create a credentials object by reading the form
    const credentials = ...;

    // return a valid redux action
    return {
      type: "LOGIN",
      credentials
    };
  )
});
const LoginForm = LoginFormConnector(LoginFormPresenter);

// Create an ad hoc middleware
//
const middleware = ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {

  if (action.type === "LOGIN") {
    // log your user
    fetch()
      .then(user => next({ type: "LOGIN", user }));

    return next({ type: "PROCESSING_LOGIN" }); // indicate to redux that you are processing the request
  }
  // let all others actions pass through
  return next(action);


};
```

So the mechanism works like this:

- The `LoginFormConnector` will inject a props `logUser` into any component it is applied to. This props is a function wich dispatches an action with the credentials of your user. It will also inject a `user` props taken from the redux state for you to show your user.
- Inside a redux middleware you catch the action and use your generic `fetchData` to process the request. When the request is resolved you dispatch the action to the reducer and update it. No data fetching occurs in the component itself, everything is handled at the middleware level.

Comment: I don't see how this solution applies to my problem. I need a **reusable method** which fetches data with credentials stored in redux store. Could you please clarify how your solution solves this?

Comment: Okey I've created my own middleware as you wrote and it works :)